# Variable fd is accessed from within inner class Error

Tags: android

i am creating the simple listview. all items will be listed successfully. but
Toast is not working.this link of the code i got the error. `Toast.makeText(this,"hello",fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

**full code**

```
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = findViewById(R.id.List);
        ArrayList<String> fd = new ArrayList<String>();
        fd.add("roda");
        fd.add("ghh");
        fd.add("asfff");
        fd.add("jll");
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,fd);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello",fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: initialize list over oncreate method

Comment: I have added another answer. try that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(this,"hello"+fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

try this code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    private ArrayList<String> fd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = findViewById(R.id.List);
        fd = new ArrayList<String>();
        fd.add("roda");
        fd.add("ghh");
        fd.add("asfff");
        fd.add("jll");
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,fd);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello"+fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your ArrayList object at class level

```
ListView list;
ArrayList<String> fd;
```

Initialize it in `onCreate()`

```
fd = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Change your code to show toast message as follows

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello "+fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have to make `fd` accessible from inside the `OnItemClickListener`. This can be done by either declaring df globally or by making df `final`.

Second you can not use `this` inside the OnItemClickListener, for this just replace the line

```
Toast.makeText(this,"hello",fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

With this:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello",fd.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And replace the `MainActivity` with the name of your activity.